# How to use a range of values in a PostgreSQL function and to loop with a distinct interval

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I have a very simple example for the summation of two numbers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add(a integer, b integer) RETURNS integer AS
$$
  SELECT $1+$2;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

My question is how to define a range `b` `10:20`, whose values will counted up by one until the end of the range (20) is reached.

The result hast to be like this

```
res = a + b
res = a + 10
res = a + 11
res = a + 12
res = a + 13
```

When I retrieve the function add with:

```
SELECT add(1);
```

there should be the results: 11,12,13,...,21.

I didn't use loops like `FOR EACH` before (especially in the `LANGUAGE sql`).

Is it better to write those functions in `plpgsql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't use loops like FOR EACH before (especially in the LANGUAGE sql).

There are no loops in SQL. (The only exception being [RECURSIVE CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).) Functions with [`LANGUAGE sql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) (no quotes!), consist of SQL statements exclusively. If you need procedural elements like loops, you need to switch to [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) (or any other procedural language) where [looping is easy enough](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

Of course, the simple example you presented would best be solved with [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html), as other answers already pointed out.

A word of caution: best use `generate_series()` in the `FROM` list. Using it in the `SELECT` list is allowed but frowned upon because non-standard. SRF (set returning functions) might be confined to the `FROM` list in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the function `generate_series()`, documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html).

So,

```
select generate_series(1, 3)
```

Will return three rows:

```
1
2
3
```

You can use these numbers in arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select add(1, b)
from generate_series(10, 20) b
```